# Compiling VLC for Android -- Dependency issues

Tags: android, vlc, video-player

I have downloaded the latest version of VLC player source code. I have followed all the steps (for `arm 7a`) mentioned on [VLC wiki page](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/), however when I import the VLC project in Eclipse, it causes dependency issues. I resolved the `appcompat & wheelView dependency` by manually copying their jar files in "lib" folder of VLC project, however I couldn't find any `libVLC jar` file to added to VLC project.

I then tried to compile the "JNI" folder of "libVLC" project with `NDK (r10b)` & it reports couldn't find `"vlc.h & other vlc C files"`

Then just for experiment sake, I exported the "libVlc" project in jar (I know this won't work) and put that in VLC project's lib folder, though the dependency issues went away but I started getting

- `R` can't be resolved
- `IAudioService & IAudioServiceCallback` can't be resolved (these are .aidl files present interface package of VLC project)

What am I missing here? How can I successfully compile the VLC player in eclipse & run it on an Android device via eclipse?

Best Regards

Comment: Does all your .so files are generated ? just for your information You will get 4 .so files (for each CPU architecture) on sucessfully following the steps.

Comment: yes they are generated. But the project is asking for libVlc.jar. What about that?